# Prove that if $f=u+iv$ is entire and $u(z) > v(z)$ for all $z$, than $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $f=u+iv$ is entire and $u(z) > v(z)$ for all $z$, than $f$ is constant.  Could anyone give a rough proof of this?  I am studying for a test and this problem is a practice problem and I haven't been able to get it right! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sketch the domain $\operatorname{Re} z > \operatorname{Im} z$. Does that look like something you could easily transform into something bounded?

Comment: *Then*. ${}{}{}$

Comment: It is bounded by y=x? But how does this help?

Comment: Bounded as in $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant K$. You need a transformation.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think I follow.

Comment: You know Liouville's theorem, presumably. Do something with $f$ that makes Liouville's theorem applicable to the result. Do it so that you can deduce that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, we spent very little time on bounded functions and so I am struggling to see how we can transform this.  We didn't go over how to transform functions really, so I am still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* By the condition, $f$ omits the value $-\sqrt 2$, hence $g(z)=\frac1{f(z)+\sqrt 2}$ is also an entrire function.